# Can I flash another iso with startup disk creator, besides Ubuntu?

Tags: startup-disk-creator

I had a laptop and that's all.

I was dual booting Ubuntu 13.10 and window 7, but recently Windows failed and needed a recovery disk.

I am trying to make a Windows 7 recovery USB disk in Ubuntu.

I see the "Startup Disk Creator" to use an ISO file to make the USB. Does Startup Disk Creator work with a Windows .iso file?

The complicated way is use the "WinToFlash" in the Wine emulator.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed, startup disk creatos is exclusive to Ubuntu and it's flavors and you can neither use unetbootin since it's only for linux distros.

I manage to boot a windows7 install iso using MultiBoot wich installs grub in your USB stick and it's also useful to have various live systems (or a persistent installation if you want).

Main page http://liveusb.info/dotclear/

Instructions to install http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install

The site is in french buth the commands in the instructions should be easy to follow. you can (1) add the repository and install it from there, (2) download an ISO, (3) download and run a script.

It's pretty easy to use, just drag and drop the ISO. This is the current state of my USB stick:

[image]